# Using 2 libraries with a contract in a sol file

Tags: solidity, remix, library

I have a sol file with a library and also a contract.

The contract can use the library and everythings deploys correct using the solidity-browser.

If I add a new library and call a function of that new library then I get the following browser-solidity error during deployment -

```
    Error deploying required libraries: Invalid bytecode format.
```

Does solidity support a contract using multiple libraries? If it does do I then need to do something else to enable using multiple libraries in a contract?

Solidity code example -

```
library MyLibrary_1
{
    function MyLibrary_1()
    {

    }

    function TestFunction() public
    {
        uint8 value = 5 + 5;
    }
}

library MyLibrary_2
{
    function MyLibrary_2()
    {

    }

    function TestFunction() public
    {
        uint8 value = 5 + 5;
    }
}

contract MyContract
{
    function MyContract()
    {

    }

    function MyContract_function() public
    {
        MyLibrary_1.TestFunction();
        MyLibrary_2.TestFunction();
    }

    function() 
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal source to reproduce this, or export your browser-solidity workstation to a gist?  I don't believe there is enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: Added a solidity code example for the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue. Do not use underscore characters when naming a solidity library as the solidity linker cannot process this character correctly during deployment.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is a known bug to be hopefully fixed soon: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/733